# Saving time - Compiling c++ and plotting at the same time gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

Hi in order to save time whene I execute the code I command this line :

```
g++ name.cpp && ./a.out
```

where nome,cpp is the name of the file that contains the code. If I succesively I need to plot some data generated by the exucatable with Gnuplot there is a way to add in the previous line instead of writing:

```
gnuplot
plot "name2.dat"
```

?

Comment: in particular I can add && gnuplot just to open gnuplot but I cannot plot the data at the same time

Comment: 'name2.dat' is the name of the data to plot produced by the execution..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can:

```
g++ name.cpp && ./a.out && gnuplot -e "plot 'name2.dat'; pause -1"
```

gnuplot exits when you hit return (see `help pause` for more options)

if you want to start an interactive gnuplot session there is a ***dirty*** way I implemented.

```
g++ name.cpp && ./a.out && gnuplot -e "plot 'name2.dat' -
```

(pay attention to the final minus sign)

Comment: Hi , thank you a lot . It was exactly was I was looking for . Only one thing I did not understand very well . Throught you command line the terminal does not go out of the process and I have to use ctrl z to interrupt it . What I have to write if I want to go out of gnuplot o remain in gnuplot and continuee to do other things ?

Comment: Thank you a lot. And if I want to quit and return to the bash there is a way? Thank you again . You really helped me!!

Comment: type `exit` or control-d ?

Comment: Yes sure but I mean in the same line command , after the plot quits automatically. Thank you again!!!